# Developer Console: closed beta testing

Tags: android, beta-testing

I'm struggling to understand the mechanics of the closed beta testing option in the Developer Console.  And I don't find [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB) very informative.

I'm able to add users to a closed beta testing group, and sure enough those users receive the beta and all is good.

What I'm struggling with is keeping different lists separate.  In this respect, you're allowed to create more than one list, and there is a 'active' checkbox against each.

I thought I was careful with my latest beta to add a new list (with only those users I want to target for the new beta), and ensure that only that list was checked.  Then I uploaded the new beta.

But I'm finding that beta testers from *previous* beta versions have also received this new beta... they're still on another of the lists, but not on the currently active list.

So, what exact steps must I perform to ensure that there is no cross-contamination between betas?  Is there any way to opt users out of betas (after they've opted in) or do they have to do it themselves?

EDIT to add screenshot showing multiple lists (re one of the comments):

[image: multiple lists]

Comment: As far as I have used so far, you can have only 2 lists, Alphas and Betas.

Comment: ? @Bonatti I've edited my question to add a screenshot showing multiple lists within the Closed Beta Testing section

Comment: I will try to reprase myself: I have used Google play in a closed enviroment, When doing so, I had 2 APKs that could be made avaialbe, APK in "beta", and APK in "alpha", whenever any of those would be updated, the whole "betas' and alphas" would be updated. While I have not needed to send a specific update to only a smaller group, I could not see a way to do that, or controls that would allow me to